# Resultados de Jogos de Futebol no site

Tags: php, xml, api

Estou de momento a desenvolver um pequeno *website* para teste que permita ao utilizador visualizar os jogos que foram realizados assim como os seus resultados, os jogadores em campo e quando foram substituídos, as faltas, etc...

Pesquisei um pouco mas não existe muita informação acerca do assunto. A única coisa que consegui achar foi o *website* **([www.livescoreshop.com](http://www.livescoreshop.com))** que permite fazer download de uma lista XML, paga, dependendo das ligas escolhidas.

Sou novo na utilização de ***API's*** mas penso que será possível aceder a estas informações utilizando uma. A minha pergunta é se existe alguma técnica que permita fazer isto de uma forma prática.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não conheço um serviço que disponibilize todas estas informações gratuitamente. Mas exite algumas APIs free que podem te ajudar:

**Gratuitas:**

http://www.futebits.com.br/ws/api/

http://apifutebol.footstats.com.br/

http://api.football-data.org/index

http://sportsopendata.net/

https://market.mashape.com/arisalexis/soccer-odds

http://www.footytube.com/openfooty/

**Pagas**

https://football-api.com/

https://www.sportmonks.com/

Você também pode criar um Crawler que vare algum site que tenhas estas informações, e coloque estes dados em um banco de dados